# MailKit + MimeKit dll download

Tags: dll, mailkit, mimekit

i have searched thoroughly for an answer but i have not found one. I was able to download the project files for the c# project but i will like to use the MailKit library for receiving mails in Windev so the need for the dll for an easier integration. Can someone please send me a link for the download. I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 3):

You should just use NuGet packages in your project: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/1.2.20

The package includes the dlls you are looking for.

It also makes it easier to update the dlls.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I had downloaded the packages from the site but i couldnt find the dlls. In what folder are they placed if i may ask.

Comment: You're not supposed to manually extract the dll's, Visual Studio does it for you if you use NuGets the way they were intended to be used.